# Logging not working for some services for microservice project

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, logging, microservices

There are 4 microservices in our project and is deployed in tomcat server in azure vm. After a recent deployment, logs are getting generated for only 1 service. The logs for other services are missing. What could be the possible issue?

PS: log4j2 configuration is used and log path is pointed to tomcat logs folder.

Comment: Please give us some more information and show us the log configuration https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask